# Create grid data in SAS using info from another dataset

Tags: sas, grid, dataset, datastep

I need to get a dataset of a uniform grid 20x20 using info from `SASHELP.CARS` so that `x` and `y` variables are obtained as follows:

```
do y = min(weight) to max(weight) by  (min(weight)+max(weight))/20;
    do x =  min(horsepower) to max(horsepower)  by (min(horsepower)+max(horsepower))/20; 
        output;
    end;
end;
```

`Weight` and `HorsePower` are variables of `SASHELP.CARS`. Furthermore the grid dataset has to have two more columns  `EnginSizeMean LengthMean` with the same value in each row that equals `mean(EnginSize)` and `mean(Length)` from `SASHELP.CARS` (need all this to build dependency graph for regression model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the statistics you need to use.

```
proc summary data=sashelp.cars ;
  var weight horsepower enginesize length ;
  output out=stats
    min(weight horsepower)=
    max(weight horsepower)=
    mean(enginesize length)=
    / autoname
  ;
run;
```

Then use those values to generate your "grid".

```
data want;
  set stats;
  do y = 1 to 20 ;
    weight= weight_min + (y-1)*(weight_min+weight_max)/20;
    do x =  1 to 20 ;
      horsepower  =  horsepower_min + (x-1)*(horsepower_min+horsepower_max)/20;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```